# Dynamic Navigation Menu in MySQL, PDO to show one instance

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a Dynamic Navigation for a project and i would like to only show the Countries that have a City `parent_id` and also only show one instance of a City (Eg: Bangkok) if more than one.

Note: China has NO `parent_id` so this is the one NOT to show.

Not sure if possible with this setup, but here we go.

Here is the Database Table with the four columns and the `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
id  | menu      | parent_id | type
----|-----------|-----------|------
1   | China     | 0         | null
2   | Myanmar   | 0         | null
3   | Laos      | 0         | null
4   | Thailand  | 0         | null
5   | Yangon    | 2         | Tour
6   | Champasak | 3         | Tour
7   | Pakse     | 3         | Tour
8   | Bangkok   | 4         | Tour
9   | Bangkok   | 4         | Tour
10  | Bangkok   | 4         | Tour
```

This is a SNIPPET of the HTML where the `class` is instantiated

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">TOURS</a>
    <?php
    $menu = new DynamicNavigation();
    $menu->navigationTourMenu();
    ?>
</li>
```

Here is the `class`

```
class DynamicNavigation {

    public function navigationTourMenu() {
        $sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM navigation');

        if($sql->count()) {
            $rows = $sql->results();
        }

        $items  = $rows;
        $id     = '';

        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            foreach($items as $item) {
                if($item->parent_id == 0) {
                    echo '<li class="dropdown">';
                        echo '<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumb-tack"></i> ' . $item->menu . '</a>';
                        $id = $item->id;
                        $this->navigationTourSubMenu($items, $id);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    public function navigationTourSubMenu($items, $id) {
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            foreach($items as $item) {
                if($item->parent_id == $id && $item->type == 'Tour') {
                    echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="' . BASE_URL . '/search?searching=' . $item->menu . '" onClick="showProgress()"><i class="fa fa-street-view"></i> ' . $item->menu . '</a>';
                        $this->navigationTourSubMenu($items, $item->id);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    }

}
```

So is there a `query` that will do this within this setup. Any help would be greatfully received as i am not a MySQL Guru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sql insted of yours

```
SELECT distinct(nav.menu), nav.id, nav.parent_id, nav.type 
FROM navigation nav
group by  nav.menu ,  nav.parent_id, nav.type 
order by nav.parent_id
```

Comment: I think that this `query` will only take out the Country and not give me the single instance of the city. But i will give it a go

Comment: Hi @giuseppe straziota i have tried your `query` but it does what i said. The problem as such is within the `navigationTourSubMenu($items, $id)` The `foreach` loop is bringing back all the Cities. What i want is just to show one instance of a city even if the are several instances of the same City. Does this make any sence :-(

Comment: Use this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd6fab/8  I have modified the query to show only one instance for country

Comment: That `query` works PERFECT for the Cities, just what i am looking for. However, i still need to show the Countries via the `navigationTourMenu()` and the Cities via the `navigationTourSubMenu($items, $id)`

Comment: there's something that I don't understand of your code. In particular the line $item->parent_id == 0 in which you call the submenu method. Parent_id is never equal to zero so into the IF condition you'll never go.

Comment: The `$item->parent_id == 0` would show the Country within `navigationTourMenu()` and the `$item->parent_id == $id` would show the City within `navigationTourSubMenu($items, $id)`

Comment: try the code that I've modified in the answer section. Looking your code, in this way you have with a query all the counties and all the cities without double.

Comment: That work PERFECTLY. 100% thumbs up Dude. Really appreciate your help on this as i didn't want to re-write it all. Many Thanks

Comment: Let me suggest you a last thing about the navigationTourSubMenu, it's better to add a break in the if condition so you cannot does a useless check, I've ordered the items to improve the search, also..